# How to split a list of values into a variable and how to make a insert function work under a for each loop in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I am Having two Tables.

**partyList**

```
create table partyList
( 
 sno serial NOT NULL,
 Party_title text,
 Party_venue text,
 Party_date date,
 Party_list character varying,
 Amount_list text
);
```

**list**

```
create table list(    
  sno integer,
  participant_name text,
  amount_paid integer
  );
```

This is the full [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/02245/12).

I want to call a function which can insert values into both tables.
and my output should look like this .
**partyList table**

```
 | SNO | PARTY_TITLE |    PARTY_VENUE |                    PARTY_DATE |                                                         PARTY_LIST |             |AMOUNT_LIST
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   1 |       games | indoor stadium | August, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000 |            ronald;sania;sachin;pointing;samueal;gibbs;gayle;smith; |  100;200;100;100;200;100;100;100; |
    |   2 |       dance |          stage | August, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 | micheal jakson; britney ; daddy yankee; ar rehaman; jestin bebber; |200;100;100;200;100; |
```

**list table**

```
| SNO | PARTICIPANT_NAME | AMOUNT_lIST
---------------------------------------
|   1 |           ronald |      100
|   1 |            sania |      200
|   1 |           sachin |      100
|   1 |         pointing |      100
|   1 |          samueal |      200
|   1 |            gibbs |      100
|   1 |            gayle |      100
|   1 |            smith |      100
|   2 |   micheal jakson |      200
|   2 |          britney |      100
|   2 |     daddy yankee |      100
|   2 |       ar rehaman |      200
|   2 |    jestin bebber |      100
```

When i call my function by these values as in example below.

```
insert_function('games','indoor stadium','08-10-2013','ronald;sania;sachin;pointing;samueal;gibbs;gayle;smith;','100;200;100;100;200;100;100;100;'),
('dance','stage','08-15-2013','micheal jakson; britney ; daddy yankee; ar rehaman; jestin bebber;','200;100;100;200;100;');
```

Is there a `way to split` the list items **(INTEGER)** and call the insert query of the `list table` in a loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [regexp_split_to_table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_party(
    _title text, _venue text, _date date,
    _list text, _Amount_list text
)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
begin
    with cte as (
       insert into partyList(Party_title, Party_venue, Party_date, Party_list, Amount_list)
       values (_title, _venue, _date, _list, _Amount_list)
       returning sno
    ), cte2 as (
       select
           sno,
           regexp_split_to_table(_list, ';') as participant_name,
           regexp_split_to_table(_Amount_list, ';') as amount_paid
       from cte
    )
    insert into list (sno, participant_name, amount_paid)
    select sno, participant_name, amount_paid::int
    from cte2
    where participant_name is not null and participant_name <> '';
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

**[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e2f27/1)**

Actually, it's possible to write this function as SQL and not plpgsql, as you see, it's just one statement.

Comment: it helped me out! thank u :-) i'm dealing with this type of subject itself, if i am not clear in this then i text u back..

Comment: can we store the returning sno value into a variable, because it helps me to go further in my assignment..

Comment: thanks i am trying to insert values which in have 2 lists of columns..and many comparisons to be done in between..once i got a clear view of my flow i will ask for your guidelines

Comment: Hi , @Roman Pekar . if in this senario i had a list of integers then how to split them and insert into the other table..

Comment: I had Edited the Question? i Tried by doing some changes in the query but i'm getting an error that                               ERROR:  column "amount_paid" is of type integer but expression is of type text                          ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.